# in R How do I copy a data frame with a dynamic name into a static named data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, naming

I have a loop where I change values. I need to take a sequentially named data frame and assign it to a variable:

```
for(i in 1:n){
    static <- paste('dinamic' , i , sep = '')
    # more code...
}
```

In other words, I would like the code to resolve to:

```
static <- dynamic1 # when i = 1, and so forth
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the `get` function:

```
for (i in 1:n) {
    static <- get(paste('dinamic' , i , sep = ''))
    # more code...
}
```

The [R documentation about the function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html).

Answer (score 1):

another way would be to create a empty dataframe and then append your data to with each iteration. Something like below :

```
    df <- NULL
    for(i in 1:n){
    static <- paste('dinamic' , i , sep = '')
    more code...
    df <- rbind(df,static)}
```